# Avoid sending full table with MongoDB and Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to get the min and max value from some fields inside a collection. I'm not sure if this:

```
result = collection.find(date_filter, expected_projection).sort({'attribute': -1}).limit(1)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
result_a = collection.find(date_filter, expected_projection)
result_b = result_a.sort({'attribute': -1}).limit(1)
```

I don't want the server to query all the data in `result_a` from the database. Is the first line of code actually fetching every document in my collection and THEN sorting it, or just fetching the max element in the attribute field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they aren't equivalent; and MongoDB will not return the entire collection to the client - whether or not the attribute field is indexed.

When you chain operators together in a MongoDB command (e.g. `find().sort().limit()`), it is not treated by the MongoDB server as a set of separate functions to be called sequentially; it is treated as a single query which should be optimised as a whole and executed as a whole on the MongoDB server.

See the documentation on [Combining Cursor Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods) for another example of how the chaining is not taken as a sequence of independent operations:

> The following statements chain cursor methods [limit()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) and [sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort):

```js
  db.bios.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).limit( 5 )
  db.bios.find().limit( 5 ).sort( { name: 1 } )
```

> The two statements are equivalent; i.e. the order in which you chain the [limit()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) and the [sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort) methods is not significant. Both statements return the first five documents, as determined by the ascending sort order on ‘name’.

Comment: Very clear, thanks. Do you know which pattern is this? Is this a builder pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code tells MongoDB to return only the document with the lowest value for "attribute". If "attribute" is indexed, then MongoDB can directly access only that one document, and not even consider the rest of the collection.

Do this once:

```
collection.create_index([('attribute', 1)])
```

Having that index in place means you can find the highest-sorting or lowest-sorting document practically instantly.